# How to conditionally format a group of cells based on if they contain a value found in a named list?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, named-ranges

I am building a calendar in Excel where event names will populate on the appropriate dates. I have a worksheet which lists the event titles and calculates the date they'll occur in a given year based on several factors. I'd like to conditionally format the font color in cells containing the "event name" formula to signify the type of event that it is. For example: holidays are red, birthdays are purple, meetings are orange, etc.
[screenshot of calendar output worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Zfk0.png)

I named the ranges of event titles based on the color I'm using to categorize them: red, purple, orange, etc. I tried creating/applying a condition for each color, but between rule precedents, parameters, and formulas I just can't get it to work the way I'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Nettle,

The conditional formatting based on Text is very simple.

Please follow below steps = 
Select The Range where needs to be formatting applied and In Home tab > Conditional formatting >  Highlight Cells Rules > Text that contains... > [type your text] 
in the with Tab select **Custom Format** go to fill and choose your colors.

Below are the links to know more about conditional formatting, which contains how to formatting through formula's also.

Link:1
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/video-conditionally-format-text-c983d661-07b6-4932-8725-b682c4f77ce1

Link:2
https://trumpexcel.com/highlight-rows-based-on-cell-value/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can enter this formula in a the Conditional formatting and set up a bunch of rules to obtain the formatting needed. Probably easier to use a hlep cell though.

```
=INDEX($A$1:$C$1,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($A$2:$C$6=D1)*(COLUMN($A$2:$C$6))))-COLUMN($A$1)+1)
```

This assumes your table (incl. headers) are in cells A1 through C6.

Easier to look at the screenshot below:
[image]

Note that it will return the rightmost column header is there are two identical values across columns.